# React-Warning-Keys with no List or .map

Tags: reactjs, list, key

The React docs say that `A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements.`

> > But I'm getting the react keys warning without rendering a list and I don't know why.

I have this component called `ExpandableCard.js` that renders a header child conditionally:

```
  // ExpandleCard return call
  ...
  return <Card className={classes.expandableCard} classes={{ root: classes.cardRoot }}>
    <div className={classes.cardHeader}>
      { props.header ? props.header : null }
      <div className={classes.headerActions}>
        {
          expanded
            ? <KeyboardArrowUp onClick={() => { setExpanded(false) }} />
            : <KeyboardArrowDown onClick={() => { setExpanded(true) }} />
        }
        { props.editable && props.onRemove ? <Close onClick={props.onRemove} /> : null }
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
    // renders children
   <Card/>
```

When I render the component normally using composition:

```
...
return <ExpandableCard header={<h4 className={c.cardTitle}>{t('record_summary.summary')}</h4>}>
    {Object.keys(displayKeys).map((d, i) => {
      return <DetailRow title={d} value={displayKeys[d]} key={i} />
    })}
  </ExpandableCard>
}
```

I get the react warning error

```
react-dom.development.js:530 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html for more information.
    in div
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by ForwardRef(Card))
    in ForwardRef(Card) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Card)))
    ...
```

> I initially thought that it was an error with the list I was rendering with the mapping of the DetailRow children, but I found out that when I rendered the `header` prop with a key, the error went away:

`return <ExpandableCard header={<h4 key={'header-for-record-summary'} ...`

**Why would react warn me about keys on a dom element that isn't getting mapped into a list?**

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm also using HOCs. Have you found an explanation?

Comment: yes I did, it was a babel issue, I'll post it as the answer. hopefully it's the same as your issue

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. You saved me so much time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found my issue to be with enabling `@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements` in a development environment.

By changing it to be enabled in production only, my errors went away:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [...],
  presets: [...],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

According to [babel documentation on the plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements):

> This transform should be enabled only in production (e.g., just before minifying your code) because, although it improves runtime performance, it makes warning messages more cryptic and skips important checks that happen in development mode, including propTypes.